# Ethernet connection regularly dying on 20.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, 20.04

I have a fresh copy of 20.04 running on a Gigabyte Brix GB-BRi3H-8130, connected to my network with gigabit ethernet. Previously, there were no issues with the network. Some time around moving to 20.04 (initially an upgrade from 19.10, and then a clean install hoping to fix this issue), the network used to be totally fine. I'm not sure if it was 20.04 that caused the problem, but it happened *around that time*.

What happens is the system becomes unreachable via SSH or ping. When I turn the TV on (it's a HTPC), I can see it's fully responsive, but the network is down. When I go to settings -> network, it says "Network Manager needs to be running". A restart fixes the problem, but after a day or two, it always seems to resurface.

I did an `ifconfig`, but there was no 'eth0'. After the restart, I can see it's actually 'enp0s31f6', so I'll have to wait until the problem happens again to see what ifconfig shows.

Any advice on how I can narrow down and diagnose the problem?

Comment: Datasheet says Ethernet is Intel i219V

Comment: Is this related? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294753/intel-ethernet-connection-i219-v-not-working-under-linux-on-an-asuspro-b-laptop I vaguely remember something about a checksum in the logs